# sending email with sendmail - django

Tags: django, email

I set up the `sendmail` email backend with [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1864/)

I open the shell and run (with actual email accounts):

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

After that, the console just prints a:

> 1

No error messages or anything... but the emails never arrive on the other end...

Is there anything else that I need to configure?

Thanks,

---

Requested the mail server's error logs from my hosting provider and saw this:

```
 send_to_gateway router failed to expand "${perl{mailtrapheaders2}}": 
 Undefined subroutine &main::mailtrapheaders2 called.\n`
```

They are still trying to figure it out :S

Comment: Which mail server do you user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the snippet code:

```
def send_messages(self, email_messages):
    """
    Sends one or more EmailMessage objects and returns the number of email
    messages sent.
    """
```

which returns a variable `num_sent` which is incremented for every mail that has been actually sent. This is the `1` your are seeing displayed in the console.

Comment: ok got it! but the problem is that the emails are not being sent or not being received at the other end...

Comment: @alexBrand from the error logs you posted it seems to be a hosting issue with exim. For info on how to try to fix it, check `http://www.webhostingtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-270504.html`

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is in your mail server. sendmail connects to the mail server and tells him "take this mail and send it to adress X". If the mail server is working it takes is and says OK, and then tries to send it to the address - if something breaks during the send its mail server error and it is not send to Django.

Check your mail server log, I believe you will find the answer of "why is the main not delivered" there.

Comment: I checked logs and added error to question.. check edit please :)

Comment: No idea, it seems more like a question for Server Fault, ask for this error there )